# How to export SQL Server Database Data into Excel in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am new to Silverlight.

I am using VS-2008 with Silverlight 3, SQL Server 2005.

My requirement is that: I have to retrieve data from Database and to export to Excel.

I have googled, but I am not getting proper link or material to meet my requirement.

Can anybody please guide me how to do it?

Advance thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way is to use NPOI (npoi.codeplex.com)..
>
> Basically, you can define the following event in your xaml:
>
> ```
> private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     WebClient client = new WebClient();
>     client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
>     client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("DownloadFile.aspx", UriKind.Absolute));
> }
> ```
>
> and after the following in your server project page DownloadFile.aspx:

```
using NPOI.HPSF;
using NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

public partial class DownloadFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = "test.xls";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename));
    Response.Clear();

    InitializeWorkbook();
    GenerateData();
    Response.BinaryWrite(WriteToStream().GetBuffer());
    Response.End();
}

HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook;

MemoryStream WriteToStream()
{
    //Write the stream data of workbook to the root directory
    MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
    hssfworkbook.Write(file);
    return file;
}

void GenerateData()
{
    Sheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

    sheet1.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("This is a Sample");
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        Row row = sheet1.CreateRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            // add you data from the db
            row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(x++);
        }
    }
}

void InitializeWorkbook()
{
    hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    ////create a entry of DocumentSummaryInformation
    DocumentSummaryInformation dsi = PropertySetFactory.CreateDocumentSummaryInformation();
    dsi.Company = "NPOI Team";
    hssfworkbook.DocumentSummaryInformation = dsi;

    ////create a entry of SummaryInformation
    SummaryInformation si = PropertySetFactory.CreateSummaryInformation();
    si.Subject = "NPOI SDK Example";
    hssfworkbook.SummaryInformation = si;
    }
}
```

> Check also the samples in the NPOI release...
>   I hope it helps!

Source: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Question/easiest-npoi-codeplex-basically-define-817046.aspx

Comment: Hi Hidde,
Thank you very much for your reply; But, I am not allowed to install new Software (NPOI) on the server. Server is located in France and I am in India. Hence, could you please suggest me some otehr approach which does not require installation of some other software!!??

Comment: You might take a look at this: http://www.rshelby.com/post/exporting-data-from-silverilght-datagrid-to-excel.aspx

Comment: Hi Hidde.

In the link you have given, we can export data from DataGrid to Excel but NOT from Database to Excel. As my post explains about my requirement, I want some functionality to export data from Database to Excel.